# no function or associated item named new_v3 found for struct uuid::Uuid in the current scope

Tags: rust

I need to add uuid in one of my struct. I found [one crate for `uuid` support](https://docs.rs/uuid/0.8.1/uuid/index.html). I added the dependency to my Cargo.toml

```
uuid = "0.8.1"
```

It downloaded fine but I can't use the function `Uuid::new_v3()`. I get the error: `no function or associated item named new_v3 found for struct uuid::Uuid in the current scope`.

The weird part for me is that I can use some of them like `from_slice` works fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify uuid's features you're planing to use.

You can add `new_v3` support by adding `v3` feature like this:

```
uuid = { version = "0.8", features = ["v3"] }
```

More info can be found [there](https://docs.rs/uuid/0.8.1/uuid/index.html#dependencies)